# Is there a better way than placing includes in namespaces?

Tags: c++, sdl, game-development

I'm structuring a c++ game, which works with an engine library that applies all the necessary rendering and the such to the game. I want to separate the namespace into multiple files, so I've created my entity class into two separate files and did this to include it in the namespace:

```cpp
namespace engine {
  void init();
  void end();

  #include "entity/entitiy.hpp" // <- holds the entity class (pretty much copies it over)
};
```

This compiles and works perfectly fine. For some reason this feels like some sort of cheat, (probably because includes are usually put at the beginning of a c++ program) and I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve this.

Comment: What namespaces are you using in `entity/entitiy.hpp`? Anyone using that file directly may be confused by the definitions of the same classes/functions is two namespaces, one of which is nested inside another. I think you'd better stick to including the header files in the global namespace.

Comment: @tedLyngmo I don't have any namespaces in entity/entity.hpp , it's solely a class named entity.

Comment: You should review [gamedev.se], if you are working on game development.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews This question covers theories in c++, such as structuring namespaces into multiple files, I'm not covering the actual design of the game specifically.

Comment: Your trick is unnecessary.   There is nothing preventing distinct parts of a namespace being spread across multiple headers and source files.   Unlike (say) a class definition (which needs to be defined in exactly the same way everywhere, since defining it in two different ways gives undefined behaviour) a namespace can be "opened" to add additional declarations within it at any times.

Comment: @Peter thanks :) didn't know that until yesterday :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to separate the namespace into multiple files

> I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve this.

Multiple namespace declarations of same name are simply declarations of the same namespace. There is no need to use your trick to define a class inside a namespace.

You can achieve defining the `entity` class within the `engine` namespace, while separating the namespace into multiple files like this:

```
// entity/entitiy.hpp
namespace engine {
  class entity { /**/ };
};

// another/header.hpp
namespace engine {
  void init();
  void end();
};
```

> ```
> namespace engine {
>   void init();
>   void end();
>
>   #include "entity/entitiy.hpp" // <- holds the entity class (pretty much copies it over)
> };
> ```
>
> This compiles and works perfectly fine.

This is a bad idea. If "entity/entitiy.hpp" is intended to be included by the user of the library, they'll end up defining the class outside of the `engine` namespace, thus defining a separate class.

Furthermore, if you include anything within "entity/entitiy.hpp", then those includes end up within `engine` namespace which in many cases is undesirable.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :D I'm debugging this right now with a couple of issues... It's probably just something with cmake, I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Thanks again for the edit, I knew that there was something wrong with my code. I'm getting some undefined references for my functions though, which I'm declaring in the class and then writing in an entity.cpp file, I use the following to grab the function: `engine::entity::change()` My lsp takes everything in correctly, but not cmake...

Comment: Found out it was a cmake error on my end, thanks!